# changing ampersands to %26

Tags: python, python-requests, ampersand

I am using `Python-requests` to pull data from a website. I am doing this currently :

```
params = {'A':'something', 'B':'something'}

response = requests.get(url, params = params)
```

which gives me: `https://someurl?query=&A=something&B=something`
This is all perfectly fine and great.

However, the website doesn't accept my API call. After some meddling around, I discovered that my target url is actually this:
`https://someurl?query=%26A=something%26B=something`

Hence my question : Is there a workaround for this problem? I have combed through requests' documentation and found nothing. I really don't feel like working with the url directly because I really like `Python-requests`.

Comment: What are the actual parameters required for your endpoint? Is it just a single `query` parameter like you seem to be suggesting? Passing in params like that will not satisfy that call

Comment: Is there a test form to query the API that you can see URLs being called in web browser console?

Comment: the actual parameters are 'groupName', 'symbols.[symbolName]', 'from' and many others. These are copied from the 'instruction manual' for the API @Jeff Mercado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL `https://someurl?query=&A=something&B=something` is very different than the URL `https://someurl?query=%26A=something%26B=something`.

URL1 `https://someurl?query=&A=something&B=something` is interpreted by the HTTP server as a request with 3 parameters: {
"query": "",
"A": "something",
"B": "something"
}

URL2 `https://someurl?query=%26A=something%26B=something`  is interpreted by the HTTP server as a request with 1 parameter: {
"query": "&A=something%26B=something"
}

where "%26" is decoded as "&" character so value is decoded as `&A=something&B=something`.

A HTTP query with a single parameter "query" with value of `&A=something&B=something` needs to be properly encoded otherwise it will be converted into the wrong value. If using params options in requests API then the encoding is automatically done for you.

```python
url = "http://localhost:8000"
params = {'query': '&A=something&B=something'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(response.status_code)
```

If you want to debug requests under the covers then add this before calling requests.get().

```
import requests
import logging

# You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

url = "http://localhost:8000"
params = {'query': '&A=something&B=something'}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:8000
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:8000 "GET /?query=%26A%3Dsomething%26B%3Dsomething HTTP/1.1" 200 5
```

Notice the "=" in the URL is also enocded to avoid any confusion since "&" and "=" are special characters in URL string.

Comment: @lizardformation - you need to review the API of the website you're using - either single parameter query or multiple parameters; e.g. A=something  B=something,

Comment: Hello CodeMonkey,
Sorry I accidentally pressed enter in the previous message. Thanks for your very detailed answer. I have since tinkered around more and compared my website's API with other traditional APIs. I realized there are some really weird conventions adopted on my website. For example, the base url is this 'someapi.co/somepath?query='. I have noticed that normally base urls do not end with 'query='. Another bizarre thing was calling this url works, 'someapi.co/somepath?query=param1=somevalue%26param2=anothervalue'.

Comment: And there are also other oddities which I will leave out here. At this point, I think I will chalk it up to the weird conventions adopted on the website and call it a day. Nevertheless, I really appreciate the effort you put into helping me and in hindsight, my question was badly defined due to me not being familiar with urls and APIs so excuse me for that

Comment: That's a single HTTP parameter. You can either hard code the full URL someapi.co/somepath?query=param1=somevalue%26param2=anothervalue or break it apart and use params = { 'query": "param1=somevalue&param2=anothervalue" } and requests will encode it for you.

Comment: No problem. Hope the answer helped you better understand the nuances of URLs and URL encoding.

Comment: Right thanks, i think i will just work with the url directly. I will give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`urllib.parse.unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) before sending requests to the server :

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

url="https://someurl?query=%26A=something%26B=something"
print(unquote(url))
# https://someurl?query=&A=something&B=something
```

And now you can send requests normally.